# Hyperparameters tuning on GANs

Tags: hyperparameter, gan

I have seen this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503907/how-to-use-hyperopt-or-perform-hyperparamter-tuning-on-a-gan) talking about how to tune hyperparameters on GANs. I'm actually wondering, more generally, how does one go about tuning hyperparameters on GANs.

Obviously you cannot (I mean you could but that wouldn't be very efficient) use a human to judge if after the training is done with some hyperparameters if the images generated are better than with other hyperparameters.

You can't either minimize the generator loss, because your GAN would converge to hyperparameters that lead to a very bad discriminator.

You can't either minimize the discrimnator loss, because your GAN would converge to hyperparameters that lead to a discrimanator that becomes too good too quickly and in which the generator only outputs images that the discriminator sees as False and then the generator cannot learn anything.

I was thinking of minimizing the sum of the generator and discriminator losses after x epoch as a function of hyperparameters? Or some more complex but well thought out function of the generator and discriminator loss to avoid the pitfalls mentionned earlier.

I don't want to use an exterior discriminator (because if not human, we would be limited by its quality). And I don't want to rely on looking at the images (even though I understand it could be done and is usually what researchers do?)

Does the answer depend on what types of GANs we do (simple ones that just generate images that are similar to a training set VERSUS CycleGANS that try to transform one image into another for example).

Comment: Should I have posted to AI.stackexchange? I didn't actually know which stackexchange to use.